# Как сделать циклическую анимацию появления текста по буквам?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Хотел сделать анимацию в прелоадер нужно было сделать так чтобы из списка предложений выводились рандомные предложение с определенной периодичностью.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я короче пытался сделать но точно так сделать у меня не выходит. Я разделил слова на буквы через плагин splitting.js. И пытался повторить эту анимацию но из за малого опыта не получается его реализовать

Answer (score 4):

Я обычно [typed.js](https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js) использовал.
На всякий случай, вдруг пригодится.

```js
var typing = new Typed(".text", {
  strings: ["Pilaton", "Web Developer"],
  typeSpeed: 100,
  backSpeed: 60,
  loop: true,
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.iam {
  color: white;
  font-size: 55px;
  padding: 15px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  border-right: 2px solid rgb(62, 216, 255);
  font-size: 55px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: rgb(62, 216, 255);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typed.js/2.0.11/typed.min.js"></script>

<div class="iam">I am</div>
<div class="text"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы в правильном направлении думаете. Разбейте строку на массив букв, после чего выводите их на экран с определённой задержкой, используя `setInterval` или `setTimeout`